# Is the usage of useSyncExternalStore in my React application reasonable for managing game state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React application where I'm managing the game state using a custom hook called `useGameManager`, which internally uses the `useSyncExternalStore` hook from an external library. The game state is encapsulated within a `GameManager` class, and I want to ensure that the usage is appropriate.

```js
import { useSyncExternalStore } from 'react'

class GameManager {
  size: number
  private listeners: VoidFunction[] = []

  constructor() {
    this.size = 4
  }

  changeSize() {
    this.size *= 2
    this.notifyListeners()
  }

  reset = () => {
    this.size = 4
    this.notifyListeners()
  }

  subscribe(listener: VoidFunction) {
    this.listeners.push(listener)

    // Return an unsubscribe function
    return () => {
      this.unsubscribe(listener)
    }
  }

  private notifyListeners() {
    for (const listener of this.listeners)
      listener()
  }

  private unsubscribe(listener: VoidFunction) {
    const index = this.listeners.indexOf(listener)
    if (index !== -1)
      this.listeners.splice(index, 1)
  }

  handleKeyDown = () => {
    this.changeSize()
  }
}

export const gameManager = new GameManager()

function getSnapshot() {
  return gameManager.size
}

function getServerSnapshot() {
  return gameManager.size
}

export function useGameManager() {
  const subscribe = (onStoreChange: VoidFunction) => {
    const unsubscribe = gameManager.subscribe(onStoreChange)
    window.addEventListener('keydown', gameManager.handleKeyDown)

    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', gameManager.handleKeyDown)
    }
  }

  return useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot, getServerSnapshot)
}
```

```js
export default function GameBoard() {
  const size = useGameManager()
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{size}</p>
      <button onClick={gameManager.reset}>reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have reviewed the official React documentation and searched Google.